# redux store.dispatch not working within nesting component

Tags: redux

I did experimental work to deeply dilute its complexity, but it did not work. While I click the `+` button, no reaction. To quick start and imagine what I said for helpers, I create it in the link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FjnUOZvyN0ft0jxq

```
const reducer=(state=0,action)=>{
  switch(action.type){
    case'INCREMENT':return state+1;
    case'DECREMENT':return state-1;
    default:return state;
  }
}
const {createStore}=Redux;
const store = createStore(reducer);

const Counter=()=>{
  
  return(
    <div>
    <p id='number'>{store.getState()}</p><br/>
    <button id='increment' onClick={store.dispatch({type:'INCREMENT'})}>+</button>
    <button id='decrement'>-</button>
    </div>
  
  )
}


const render=ReactDOM.render(
        <React.StrictMode>
  <Counter />
        </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
// Add your code here
store.subscribe(render);
render()
```

;

Answer (score 2):

That is not how you couple react and redux (you would need to use the react-redux library, the Provider component and the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` hook. **Never** reference `store` in one of your components directly!).

Or make react rerender at all.

Also, this is a very old style of redux that will make you write a multitude more code than you need in the end.

I suggest you follow the official redux tutorials available at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index

Comment: thanks for suggestion for learning, but the code I used are from reduxjs creator `Dan Abramov
` and his redux tutorial on `egghead.io`.And the mentor highlight this is fundamental for real-world using in the future.So now I think I have to know what happen in this code snippet and then switch to your tutorial.Thanks.

Comment: I ignore `Never reference store in one of your components directly!).`I guess it is the answer and I accept the answer even I do not know why. Thanks, if you can tell me more why can not reference directly ,i would be grateful for your generosity .If not told  ,thanks too.

Comment: Essentially that tutorial shows the basics of how react-redux was written, but is not how you should write any production code. You have missed quite a few bits of syntax if it should do anything like that., namely multiple `() =>`.
 Using `store` directly means you have to take control over when rerenders happen (which as you noticed) is quite tricky. In "real life" you use the `useSelector` hook as that will take care of all that automatically.